# I can't install RouteMe in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, proj

I'm trying to install the Route-Me library in Xcode so as to convert coordinates in my iphone application.
I have follow this page : https://github.com/route-me/route-me/wiki/Embedding-Guide
However, I don't have a "MapView.app" (in paragraph "Configuring build dependencies").

I don't know how to install this library. Xcode can't compile.

Is there someone who can help me ?
Thanks

Best regards
Etienne

Comment: what is the error you are getting when compiling

Comment: leave about the .app file. do you have the .a file there. Did you successfully finished the General tab suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

if you did fallow all the steps including "Configuring build dependencies" you should have in your application tree a blue file icon named MapView.xcodeproj.

Don't forget to check the box for libMapView.a (Select the MapView.xcodeproj and then on the right you should have two files libMapView.a and another one. Check the box on the far right on the same line with libMapView.a)

In the tree of your project expand the "Targets" node and double click on the child with your app name - usually is the first child of the Targets node.(it will have a ruler and a pen as a icon).

after that you should fallow the guide that you fallowed. Don't forget to link all the extra libraries...